# Mismatch in account shown in Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, user-accounts

I am seeing there is mismatch in reputation shown in Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange. I have attached the screen shots.

The reputation in

> Apple account

is different in both the screen shots.

Why is there mismatch in reputation?

Stack Overflow account [image: Screen_Shot]

Stack Exchange account [image: Screen_Shot1]

Comment: Two points...probably not a bug. More likely a caching issue. Did you just recently accept an answer on the Apple site?

Comment: I have not accepted the answer recently.

Comment: This issue I am seeing this mismatch from 3 days, while there is no change in reputation in past 3 days.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now there is no mismatch in reputation on stackexchange and SO.